# Mathematical proof of maximum possible number of palindromic substrings possible in a string?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

I need to prove that in a string with a number of characters n, at most n distinct, non-empty palindromic substrings are possible. I can understand that this is because every character can be a palindrome in and of itself, and so the max possible number of substrings possible is going to be equal to the number of characters in the string. However, I cannot seem to express this in the form of mathematical proof. How can I do so?

Comment: `aaa` size 3: `a`, `a`, `a`, `aa`, `aa`, `aaa`, count 6. That seems to disprove your assertion. I don't get it. Unless you discount single characters?

Comment: I mentioned "distinct". In your case, if we count only the distinct palindromes, then we will count a, and aa only once and not three a's and two aa's.

Comment: So items are indistinct. Maybe with a recurrence; one shows that, with another item, the maximum one can be added? Maybe CS or Math would get you more results?

Comment: A recurrence on the number of characters seems like a good idea. If you have a string with n+1 character, consider the possibilities for the last character: it might or might not be equal to a character present in the first n characters. How many palindromes does every case add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given *xc*, where *x* is any string and *c* is any character:

All substrings of *xc* that are not already in *x* must be *suffixes* of *xc*.  If they're palindromes, then they have the form *cyc*, where *cy* is a suffix of *x* and *y* is a palindrome or empty.

Imagine that there are two such new palindromic suffixes.  Since they are distinct suffixes of the same string, they must be different lengths, so we have *cyczc*, where *z* and *ycz* are both palindromes or empty.

If *ycz* is a palindrome, there are a few cases to consider.

1. If len(y) = len(z), then that would imply that *y = z* and that *czc*, therefore, was *already* a substring of *x* -- a contradiction.
2. If *z* is shorter, then we can partition again into *cz<sup>r</sup>cwczc*, but *z* is a palindrome so *z<sup>r</sup>* = *z* and we have the same contradiction.
3. If *z* is longer, then we can partition into *cycwcy<sup>r</sup>c*, with *wcy<sup>r</sup>* = z, and that's a palindrome, so also z = *ycw* and again the contradiction that *czc* already appears in *x*.

So... adding a single character to a string can introduce *at most one* new palindromic substring.  The total number of such substrings in any string, therefore, cannot be more than the string's length.

Comment: What about 1-character strings?

Comment: 1-character strings are trivial -- they're only new if there are no other occurrences of that character in the string, in which case the only palindromic suffix is the single character.

Comment: In terms of the proof, there is nothing about 1-character strings that invalidates the assertion that if you have two new palindromic suffixes, then you must have the cyczc form.